# Cannot kill process: "No process is associated with this object" error

Tags: c#, process

In my program I try to start a new process (open video file in a default player). This part works OK. Later when I try to close the process (player) I get an error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: No process is associated with this object.

My code:

```
string filename = "747225775.mp4";
var myProc = new Process()
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(filename)
};
myProc.Start();
Thread.Sleep(5000);
try
{
    myProc.Kill(); //Error is here
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(ex);
    Debugger.Break();
}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: The program has likely already finished when you try to kill it

Comment: Try adding `Debug.WriteLine(myProc.MainModule.FileName);` immediately after the Start() call. You may find that the process that is launched by specifying the .mp4 file is a short-lived process that starts something else and exits. Or not - it depends on your system configuration.

Comment: Or duos not start

Comment: I'd imagine that it would be obvious if the process wasn't starting because there would be no movie on the screen

Comment: @RobHill process starts OK and video is playing

Comment: What do you see when you add the Debug.WriteLine statement above? Is it the same program that is playing the video?

Comment: You can also try `Debug.WriteLine(myProc.Id);`, look at the number that prints, then compare that number to the "PID" column in Task Manager for the process that is playing the video. If they don't match, that's another sign that the original process launched something else and ended itself.

Comment: You have not provided enough information for anyone to provide a proper answer. When you start an MP4 file, you are not launching a specific application. On my machine, it would launch VLC. On yours, it might launch mplayer2 for all I know. Or you could have some other program installed that I've never even heard of. Because you are not specifying the exact path of an executable, I cannot possibly tell you what the behavior of the executable that is actually launching would be. I have your code on my machine and am currently exploring possibilities. I was hoping you could do the same.

Comment: @RobHill I don't provide application name/path (vlc or other) but only file name to make the application use user default player.

Comment: If my default player was "cmd.exe /c start %1" your program would fail exactly as you described. Unless you provide additional information, any attempts to solve the problem will be shots in the dark.

Comment: @RobHill that turned out to be incorrect in that `cmd.exe` will actually propagate the Process properties, like `HasExisted` and `Id`, in a manner that will not throw `InvalidOperationException` with a get accessor usage.. the OP actually was experiencing irregular behavior and expectations here; it's not simply a matter of the process closing before a call to `Exit`.  it's strange.

Answer (score 2):

`Process.Start` associates the `Process` object with native process handle only when it spawns new process directly. When filename is used as an argument instead of executable name, `Process` searches registry for association settings via *shell32.dll* functions and the exact behavior depends on them.

When association is configured in traditional way, to call command line and transfer file name as 1st argument (such as for Notepad), `Process.Start` spawns new process directly and correctly associates object with native handle. However, when association is configured to execute COM-object (such as for *Windows Media Player*),  `Process.Start` only creates some RPC query to execute COM object method and returns without associating object with process handle. (The actual process spawn occurs in *svchost.exe* context, according to my tests)

This issue can be solved by following modified process start method:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ProcessTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        [DllImport("Shlwapi.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern uint AssocQueryString(AssocF flags, AssocStr str, string pszAssoc, string pszExtra, [Out] StringBuilder pszOut, ref uint pcchOut);

        /*Modified Process.Start*/
        public static Process TrueProcessStart(string filename)
        {
            ProcessStartInfo psi;
            string ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(filename);//get extension

            var sb = new StringBuilder(500);//buffer for exe file path
            uint size = 500;//buffer size

            /*Get associated app*/
            uint res = AssocQueryString(AssocF.None, AssocStr.Executable, ext,null, sb, ref size);

            if (res != 0)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("AssocQueryString returned error: " + res.ToString("X"));
                psi = new ProcessStartInfo(filename);//can't get app, use standard method
            }
            else
            {
                psi = new ProcessStartInfo(sb.ToString(), filename);
            }

            return Process.Start(psi);//actually start process
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            string filename = "c:\\images\\clip.wmv";

            var myProc = TrueProcessStart(filename);
            if (myProc == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Process can't be killed");
                return;
            }

            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            try
            {
                myProc.Kill(); 
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    [Flags]
    enum AssocF : uint
    {
        None = 0,
        Init_NoRemapCLSID = 0x1,
        Init_ByExeName = 0x2,
        Open_ByExeName = 0x2,
        Init_DefaultToStar = 0x4,
        Init_DefaultToFolder = 0x8,
        NoUserSettings = 0x10,
        NoTruncate = 0x20,
        Verify = 0x40,
        RemapRunDll = 0x80,
        NoFixUps = 0x100,
        IgnoreBaseClass = 0x200,
        Init_IgnoreUnknown = 0x400,
        Init_FixedProgId = 0x800,
        IsProtocol = 0x1000,
        InitForFile = 0x2000,
    }

    enum AssocStr
    {
        Command = 1,
        Executable,
        FriendlyDocName,
        FriendlyAppName,
        NoOpen,
        ShellNewValue,
        DDECommand,
        DDEIfExec,
        DDEApplication,
        DDETopic,
        InfoTip,
        QuickTip,
        TileInfo,
        ContentType,
        DefaultIcon,
        ShellExtension,
        DropTarget,
        DelegateExecute,
        SupportedUriProtocols,
        Max,
    }


}
```

Here we get the file type's associated application via [AssocQueryString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773471%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). The returned value is then passed to `ProcessStartInfo`. However it does not always work, so we sometimes have to resort to standart method. For example, image files does not have any associated exe, it's just dll being loaded into explorer's process. So we can't outright kill process in this case.

Answer (score 0):

to answer your question: "What is wrong?"

I can say the underline cause of this is related to Windows Apps that are launched to handle the type of file (`.mp4`).

---

From what I can determine.. there isn't anything wrong with your code sample except that it doesn't account for this scenario (in which, admittingly, I do not understand why it behaves this way).

---

To replicate this, I used your code sample and a image file (`.png`).  the program launches with 'Photos' by default.

I changed `.png` files to launch with `Paint` application by default, then ran the program again. The code sample you've provided worked fine on the desktop application.